# How access to the security token of a community user

Tags: soap-api

I writing some unit tests in `Scala` in which I make a login using `soap` in order to access to the session ID needed to make calls to the REST API. There is one missing data to log using `soap`, it's the security user. If I'm a SF User, I can reset my security token but if I'm a community user, in the personnal settings, I only can change my password. How I can resolve my problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community User license type doesn't have security token.

Comment: In this case, how I can acess to the session ID of a such user ? I mean in a programmatically way.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand PHP, [this link at SFDC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_Login_Sample_%28Partner%29) should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is no security token concept on communities.